# Dart, Is it possible to pass on the members of an interface implicitly?

Tags: interface, dart

In Dart I have a class:

```
class A implements Iterable<MyType>{

    List<MyType> children;

    //other members for A class

}
```

Is it possible, without using `noSuchMethod`, to implicitly forward all of the `Iterable<MyType>` methods to the `List<MyType> children;` member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible to delegate without `noSuchMethod` or without implementing all members.

An other way can be to use [IterableBase](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_collection/IterableBase.html) and only implement [Iterable.iterator](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/Iterable.html#iterator) like this :

```dart
import 'dart:collection';
class A extends IterableBase<MyType> {
  List<MyType> children;
  Iterator<MyType> get iterator => children.iterator;
}
```

Note that this could be less performant than implementing and delegating every members directly to `children`.

Comment: nice use of IterableBase